Unable to display local storage value in chrome extension popup.html
I am working on an extension that will grab a value from the current page's url and display it in the popup.html and pass the value to an external API. In the content-script.js I am parsing the value from the url then storing it in local storage. When the extension is activated, it gets the value from local storage and I want to display it in a text field on the popup.html in an input control with the id="Job_Id".
manifest.json
    {
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "JTJobId",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "JobTracker JobId",
    "author": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/icon.png",
            "48": "images/icon.png",
            "128": "images/icon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "JT Job ID"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*.jt.net/*"],
          "js": ["content-script.js"]
        }
      ]
}

popup.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content=""IE=Edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Job Id</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./popup.css"
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="./popup.js"></script>
        <div>
            <label for="Job_Id">Job ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="Job_Id" id="Job_Id" placeholder="Job Id">
          </div>
    </body>
</html>



popup.js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    var jobId = 'xxxx';
    chrome.storage.local.get(["jobId"]).then((result) => {
        jobId = result.jobId;
        console.log(jobId);
    });   
    
    chrome.action.setBadgeText({text: jobId});
    chrome.action.setBadgeTextColor({color: '#00F'});    

    var e = document.getElementById("Job_Id");
    console.log(e);
    e.value = jobId;
});

content-script.js
var loc = window.document.location.pathname.replace('/sys/job/','');

chrome.storage.local.set({jobId: loc});
chrome.storage.local.get(["jobId"]).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.jobId);
})

When I execute the extension, The value I am expecting shows up in the console for popup.js when this code block executes:
    chrome.storage.local.get(["jobId"]).then((result) => {
        jobId = result.jobId;
        console.log(jobId);
    }); 

However, the value 'XXXX' is displayed in the textbox on the popup, which runs after the storage.local.get(....).

This is what the console shows for popup.html:

What am I missing?

Remove content_scripts, content.js, and storage calls. Use chrome.tabs.query to get the current URL in popup directly, example.
